# If выражения в gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-runner

Можно ли при использовании `shell-runner` передавать `if` выражения на удаленном 
сервере?

Вот такой вот тестовый gitlab-ci.yml:

```
world_branch:
  variables: 
    dir: "/home/TATATA"
  environment: staging
  script:
  - ssh-keyscan -H 192.168.0.12 >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  - ssh root@192.168.0.12 "
      'if [[ -d "$dir" ]]; then
          rm -r $dir && mkdir $dir
          fi'
       "
  - rsync -avz --delete-after --exclude=".git" --exclude=".gitlab-ci.yml" . root@192.168.0.12:/home/TATATA
  only: 
   - world
```

После запуска задания, вот такая ошибка:

```
bash: if [[ -d /home/TATATA ]] rm -r /home/TATATA && mkdir /home/TATATA fi: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

Решилось только таким способом:

```
- ssh root@192.168.0.12 "
      if [[ -d "$dir" ]]; then
          rm -r $dir && mkdir $dir;
      fi
      "
```

То есть нужно после shell команды поставить ;

Для конструкций где shell команд две и более, нужно просто добавлять в конец каждой опять же ;

Например:

```
- ssh root@192.168.0.12 "
    if [[ ! -d "$dir" ]]; then
       mkdir $dir;
       mkdir $dir/test;
    fi
    "
```